# ubuntu nvidia driver installation fails

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

I have rtx3090ti nvidia driver and install the latest nvidia driver across diverse ways such as from additional drivers app or apt install. Both does not work the output is always the same.

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

And now i am trying to install recommended version with the following command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525-open
```

which returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-525-open : Depends: libnvidia-gl-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: nvidia-dkms-525-open (<= 525.78.01-1) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: nvidia-dkms-525-open (>= 525.78.01) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-525 (>= 525.78.01) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libnvidia-compute-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libnvidia-extra-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libnvidia-decode-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libnvidia-encode-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: nvidia-utils-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-525 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 525.60.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.8) but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libnvidia-compute-525:i386 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
                          Recommends: libnvidia-decode-525:i386 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
                          Recommends: libnvidia-encode-525:i386 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
                          Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
                          Recommends: libnvidia-gl-525:i386 (= 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

now i have secure boot enabled because otherwise the computer does not start and stuck in 0x91 Driver installation step. I installed the nvidia driver while secure boot enabled before and it worked. Now i don't know what may be causing the problem.

Comment: At least libnvidia-gl-525:i386 is in phased state. And maybe others packages too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the system couldn't communicate because nvidia-drivers are not included by bios. So the setup stops at 0x91 step.
To resolve the problem nvidia-drivers should be allowed by MOK manager.

Details about MOK manager and nvidia-driver installation can be found at the following blog post:
[Nvidia-driver installation and MOK](https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2022/07/29/solved-nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-make-sure-that-the-latest-nvidia-driver-is-installed-and-running/)

Answer (score 5):

I tried the following and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-* -y
sudo apt autoremove
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

Comment: FYI to others: during autoinstall I get the following error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment

Comment: For me the screen went black during `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and I had to reset the computer.